# My application in ASP.NET sometimes identifies procedures of postgresql and sometimes shows error "this procedure does not exist"

Tags: c#, postgresql, stored-procedures

**I have an application currently fully operational using OracleDB.Recently, I converted my OracleDB into PostgreSQL and I am facing a weird problem.Whenever I try to access my procedure of PostGreSQL through application, sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes does not.It gives an error saying that "this procedure(my procedure name) does not exist,while it exists in the database and works perfectly with pgAdmin query tool. I am really confused,please help me out. Here I am giving one of my sample procedure below and attaching error log too.**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sylvia.pro_occupation_add(
        p_occupationid bigint,
        p_occupationname text,
        p_occupationdetails text)
        RETURNS void
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    AS $BODY$

    begin
        insert into sylvia.occupation (occupationid,occupationname,occupationdetails)
               values (p_occupationid, p_occupationname, p_occupationdetails);                      
    end; 

    $BODY$;


C# code :
private DataSet _createOccupation(DataSet inputDS)
        {
            ErrorDS errDS = new ErrorDS();
            EmployeeHistDS employeeHistDS = new EmployeeHistDS();
            DBConnectionDS connDS = new DBConnectionDS();

            //extract dbconnection 
            connDS.Merge(inputDS.Tables[connDS.DBConnections.TableName], false, MissingSchemaAction.Error);
            connDS.AcceptChanges();

            //create command
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "PRO_OCCUPATION_ADD";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            employeeHistDS.Merge(inputDS.Tables[employeeHistDS.Occupation.TableName], false, MissingSchemaAction.Error);
            employeeHistDS.AcceptChanges();

            foreach (EmployeeHistDS.OccupationRow row in employeeHistDS.Occupation)
            {
                long genPK = IDGenerator.GetNextGenericPK();
                if (genPK == -1)
                {
                    return UtilDL.GetDBOperationFailed();
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Add("p_OccupationId", genPK);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("p_OccupationName", row.OccupationName);

                if (!row.IsOccupationDetailsNull()) cmd.Parameters.Add("p_OccupationDetails", row.OccupationDetails);
                else cmd.Parameters.Add("p_OccupationDetails", DBNull.Value);

                bool bError = false;
                int nRowAffected = -1;
                nRowAffected = ADOController.Instance.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, connDS.DBConnections[0].ConnectionID, ref bError);

                if (bError == true)
                {
                    ErrorDS.Error err = errDS.Errors.NewError();
                    err.ErrorCode = ErrorCode.ERR_DB_OPERATION_FAILED.ToString();
                    err.ErrorTier = ErrorTier.ERR_TIER_DL.ToString();
                    err.ErrorLevel = ErrorLevel.ERR_LEVEL_SEVER.ToString();
                    err.ErrorInfo1 = ActionID.ACTION_OCCUPATION_ADD.ToString();
                    errDS.Errors.AddError(err);
                    errDS.AcceptChanges();
                    return errDS;
                }
            }

            errDS.Clear();
            errDS.AcceptChanges();
            return errDS;
        }

public int ExecuteNonQuery(NpgsqlCommand cmdInsertUpdateDelete, int connectionID, ref bool bError)
        {
            CConnectionInfo connInfo = (CConnectionInfo)this.m_hashConn[connectionID];
            if (connInfo == null)
            {
                AppLogger.LogWarning("Connection ID '" + connectionID + "' does not exist in connection pool.\nCould not execute ExecuteNonQuery method.");
                bError = true;
                return -1;
            }

            NpgsqlConnection conn = connInfo.m_Conn_PG;
            NpgsqlTransaction tx = connInfo.m_Tx_PG;

            cmdInsertUpdateDelete.Connection = conn;
            cmdInsertUpdateDelete.Transaction = tx;
            try
            {
                bError = false;
                return cmdInsertUpdateDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteErrorLog(ex, connectionID);

                AppLogger.LogFatal("Error executing ExecuteNonQuery method.\n" + cmdInsertUpdateDelete.CommandText, ex);
                invalidateConnectionID(connectionID);
                bError = true;
                return -1;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmdInsertUpdateDelete.Transaction = null;
                cmdInsertUpdateDelete.Connection = null;
            }

        }
```

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDHUn.png)

Comment: have you tried pasing stored procedure name as `sylvia.pro_occupation_add`. If `sylvia` is not the default schema then you need to provide the full name.

Comment: how do I do that by code?can you please help me?

Comment: set `cmd.CommandText = "sylvia.PRO_OCCUPATION_ADD";` in your c# function.